# C# LINQ Distinct(IEqualityComparer) help

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

I have a generic list where the user can add files. I'm trying to get it to delete an object if the source already exists in another object in the list. I will also mention that I'm new to using the features of System.Linq.

The list if of type MediaInfo:

```
public static List<MediaInfo> imagePlaylist = new List<MediaInfo>();
```

This is the code for the MediaInfo struct and the IEqualityComparer:

```
public struct MediaInfo
{
    public string source;
    public char? type;        
}
public class MediaInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<MediaInfo>
{
    public bool Equals(MediaInfo x, MediaInfo y)
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(string.Compare(x.source, y.source, true));

    }

    public int GetHashCode(MediaInfo obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return 0;
        int hashProductName = obj.source == null ? 0 : obj.source.GetHashCode();
        int hashProductCode = obj.type.GetHashCode();
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the Distinct(IEqualityComparer) is not working.

```
imagePlaylist = imagePlaylist.Distinct(new MediaInfoComparer()).ToList();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String compare returns Negative, 0, or positive; it's not a boolean operation. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx) link for details. So you would have two situations where it returns false, and one where it returns true. In addition, the situation where it returns true is when the strings aren't actually the same.

Basically, what you need to do is this:

```
return string.Compare(x.source, y.Source, true) == 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IEqualityComparer` logic is backwards:

[`string.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx) will return `0` when 2 strings are equal.

[`Convert.ToBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0b8dwce.aspx) will return `false` when the parameter is `0`.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the answers. I didn't even think the error was in string.Compare >.<.